# How to display all applications which run in background?

Tags: android, android-homebutton, android-recents

When I click on "Home" button, it will display applications which I open and haven't been killed on the background.

Example: First, I open WhatsApp and then go to home screen without killing it. Then I open Facebook and do the same again. Do the same with 3 or 4 other applications. Now, when I click the "Home" button or app button at that time, it will display all the applications which are in background in `ListView`.

So, my question is: How to do this when I click any of the button or "Home" button on Android device?

**Image**

[image: list of apps displayed from Home button]

Comment: Your screenshot is not "all the application which runs in background".

Answer (score 0):

```
   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

   for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {
       Log.d("RUNNING", "Application (" +i+")" +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check all Apps/Services running:

```
private void whichServiceRunning() {
  ActivityManager actiManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo : actiManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {          
            Log.d("RUNNING: ", serviceInfo.service.getPackageName());
        }
}
```

I hope this helps you